# Получение информации о цвете многоугольника (метки) на карте

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Создал на карте многоугольник и задал ему синий цвет, могу ли я как то обратиться к нему и получить информацию, о том какого он цвета?

И также узнать количество зон на карте и их подпись?

Comment: Что значит "И также узнать количество зон на карте и их подпись?" ? Можете объяснить подробнее и предоставить пример?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы узнать значение опции нужно выполнить такой код:

```
myGeoObject.options.get('fillColor')
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8eusygcm/